# Animated GIF in Splashscreen

Tags: java, ant, awt, splash-screen, animated-gif

I have a JAR file generated by an ANT script with the following code in it:

```
<manifest>
   <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.epistasis.exstracs.Main"/>
   <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
   <attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="logo_anim.gif"/>
</manifest>
<!--Some code-->
<zipfileset dir="." includes="logo.png"/>
<zipfileset dir="." includes="logo_anim.gif"/>
<zipfileset dir="." includes="icon.png"/>
```

When I run the JAR file, no splash screen is generated. I verified that the GIF was in the file by opening it with my favorite archive manager. I also loaded the GIF from the code and successfully displayed it. However, it won't load as a splashscreen. (no splashscreen displayed, `SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()` returns `null`)

If I replace

```
<attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="logo_anim.gif"/>
```

With

```
<attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="logo.png"/>
```

OR

```
<attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="icon.png"/>
```

The splashscreen is displayed with the specified image.

I'm not sure if this matters, but the GIF is significantly larger than the PNG files. (~2MB for `logo_anim.gif` vs 40KB for `logo.png`)

Comment: *"the GIF is significantly larger than the PNG files. (~2MB..!"*  It never occurred to you that 2MB is ***far too large*** for a splash screen image?!?  How big is the app. itself?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I thought it might be too large, but the image will load in the browser without a problem, and the first frame will render if I use `Graphics.drawImage`. The JAR ends up being 15MB, I think, 17 with the animated GIF.