# Animated GIF leads to SplashScreen being null

Tags: java, awt, manifest, splash-screen, animated-gif

I know this is probably close to a duplicate of this thread: [Animated GIF in Splashscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601225/animated-gif-in-splashscreen)

But since it seems unanswered and I can't comment on it or anything I'm sorry to repost this but it would be awesome if someone could give me an answer.

I am making a game and this game takes quite a lot of time to start. Therefore I want to give the user feedback during the loading screen so he knows the application hasn't crashed. That's why I use the SplashScreen API from java 7.

In eclipse, when I run my application using the following configuration in VM Arguments, `SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()` returns `null`.

`-splash:src/aapplication/Splash.gif`

But when I use this configuration, it works fine (I have to files in the same package, one is `Splash.png` and the other `Splash.gif`):

`-splash:src/aapplication/Splash.png`

In a jar file (in `MANIFEST.MF`), this doesn't work:

`SplashScreen-Image: aapplication/Splash.gif`

While this does:

`SplashScreen-Image: aapplication/Splash.png`

My GIF is about 1Mb in size while the PNG is 50kb.

Can anyone explain to me why does the GIF can't even be loaded while the PNG does (I know it's not the path since they have the same)?

Everywhere I looked, it said it should work just as fine as for PNGs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: a differenct approach can be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19294511/1283215)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find that the problem comes down to two things...

1. Using the command line parameter (-splash), Java expects the image to be a file on the file system, whereas the manifest file expects it to be an embedded resource.
2. Java doesn't seem capable of playing optimised gifs, that is gifs whose frames represent the difference between the last and current frame, instead of a complete image (as far as the splash screen goes).

I tried using

[image: Pony01]

and

[image: Pony02]

The first image failed, but the second worked, the difference, as near as I can tell, is the first is optimised and the second is not...

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do a gif that is not optimized? (I used the site myspacegens.com to create my gif and I'm kinda new to creating gifs).

Comment: Not really, tend not to do much my self.  Best bet is to find a more advance generator, one that allows you to define the DISPOSE_METHOD for each frame...

Comment: @MadProgrammer my child loves this poor cartoon (Minimax by HBO:-)

Comment: @mKorbel Thankfully, mine hasn't found it...yet :P

Comment: @Xergz Which version?

Comment: CS5 does it so probably CS6 does it too (I don't know about the other versions)