# Java -splash:file.gif option not displaying gif

Tags: java, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a simple splash intro for my program. Using the -splash argument when running the Java project works perfectly well and displays the image with a jpeg

but **not** with a gif

Exact VM arguments used;

```
-splash:resources/img/test1.gif  //Doesnt show
-splash:resources/img/test2.jpg  //Does show
```

Tested on both windows and debian; with debian able to display some gifs. But none on windows.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is it an animated GIF?

Comment: Yes its an animated gif i created in photoshop

Comment: Take a look at [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001292/animated-gif-leads-to-splashscreen-being-null/23001820#23001820)

Comment: Brilliant thank you!